# Android Frida intercept HTTP request/response

Tags: android, frida

I try to intercept the HTTP request/response message by using the Frida with Android Application.
Currently, I found the sample Frida script as below.
https://bbs.pediy.com/thread-252129.htm

But, the script did not work for me. There's nothing after I run the script (No any ERROR and no console logs appeared)

I'm not sure is it work for the application if my application has no certificate pinning? Which classes I should focus on? or how many ways to intercept the HTTP request/response message by using Frida?

I try to understand a runtime debugging. I'm a newbie in this area I hope that someone can guide/suggest me how can I start to do this.

Comment: The linked script only works for apps that are not obfuscated and that include OkHttp library. In general IMHO interception should done on network level using a proxy like mitmproxy or Fiddler, not on application level. Only use Frida scripts to disable pining.